# How to add a contact to People from Hangouts?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-apps, google-hangouts, people-app

I'm using KitKat. I have Hangouts conversations with people who are not in my contacts (this may be an artifact of using a Google Apps account provided by my school). How can I add someone from one of these conversations to People?

I have tried double-tapping and holding down their icon or their chats without any success, and looking at the "..." options menus. No luck. I do know how to add contacts from email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. View the Hangout of the unknown contact
2. In the lower left hand corner of the Hangout screen, you'll notice a small icon to the left of the text box. If you tap that, 2-3 options will be available: "Hangouts," "Mobile (via SMS)," or "Mobile (via Google Voice)."  Select "Mobile (via SMS)."
3. Open the overflow menu (three dots in the top right corner) and select People & options
4. At the bottom of the people & options menu, you'll see "People in the hangout." The phone number should say 'touch to add to contacts'. Touch it.
5. Either search for an existing contact and add the new number for that contact or you can add as new contact by using the three dot overflow menu.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, when you select "add to people" there is no option to make a new contact, only "select contact". You can only add that number to an existing contact.

Comment: Ah, ok you have to click the little button that is a person with a star next to their head. Samsung S4.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Clicking on the phone number under "People in this Hangout" does nothing. Pressing and holding also does nothing.

Comment: @TreyHunner have you already got them as a contact? I've just tried and it does nothing if they're already a contact but I still get prompted to 'Add to contacts' if not.

Comment: No I do not have their phone number in my contacts already.

Answer (score 3):

As far I know you can't add people directly from a Hangouts chat. You will need their email atleast. If you have their email ID, Open Gmail and open Contcts. Then click "Add contact" and add people with their appropriate emails.

Answer (score 2):

tap on the icon next to their text (don't tap+hold).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the SMS option is chosen as the "Send as" option and not Hangouts/Google Voice number, and the option to add contact after selecting the the dots on the conversation will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when you change the sms settings to 'default to use google voice number' it won't give you the option to change what number you send it from at the bottom. But there's another option in the overflow menu that wasn't there before to add contact, this works better for me.

Comment: What option in which overflow menu? Which app you are in there? Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: In the upper right corner of the chat message the 3 stacked dots are called the overflow menu.  +1 to answer as this is currently the correct way to do solve this.